# Changing elements in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Am new to javascript and I am trying to change a list of numbers in an array I wanted to know the best way to do this I am currently only changing the one number with a string "quad" but I wanted to change every 4 numbers with that string what is the best way to do this

```
//store the numbers in an arry 
var item = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    item.push(i);
// increment the result variable by 4
    var result = 0
    result = result + 4
    if( result < 100  ){
        var index = item.indexOf(result)
        item[index] = "quad"
//print out item replacing every four numbers with the string "quad"
    console.log(item[i])

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with modulo % if  `4` can be divisible with `i` then push `quad` to the array else push `i`

```js
var item = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
  if( i % 4 == 0 ){
    item.push('suqad');
  }
  else{
    item.push(i);
  }
  document.write(item[i]+'<br>');
}
```